# Redirect error in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-url

I am trying to the code

```
function validate(){
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('inventory/inventoryModel');
        $result = $this->inventoryModel->validateUser();
        if($result == 1){
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_loged_in' => TRUE 
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        }
        else{
            $this->index();
            redirect('inventory/validate');
        }
    }
```

and getting the error in chrome "This web page has a redirect loop"
what is solution?

Comment: The solution is to delete `redirect('inventory/validate');` from your code.

Comment: Validation fails -> redirects to validate -> validation fails on the same criteria -> redirects to validate... rinse and repeat

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
$this->index()
```

which probably trying to load views mentioned in the function.

Redirect causing again to load different function.

Sort that out. Can't give the exact solution as this isn't the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function validate(){
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('inventory/inventoryModel');
        $result = $this->inventoryModel->validateUser();
        if($result == 1){
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_loged_in' => TRUE 
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        }
        else{
            $this->index();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably call the validate function in your index function as well. Maybe you need to adds some logic to only run validate when not in index.